# postgresql jsonb update List of string value based on existing values searched in other table

Tags: postgresql, arraylist, jsonb, insert-update, jsonb-array-elements

I have two tables like these in postgres db :

```
 TABLE tag (
  id number,
  name nvarchar
);

 TABLE article (
  id number,
  tags jsonb  // List<String>   list of **name**s of tags  from tag table => should be converted 
                 to list of **Id**s from tag table
);
```

now I want to **update** the article table to keep the List of tags **Ids** instead of **names** from the **tag** table. how can I write a **update query** which for all records of article table updates tags jsonb columns and sets to the ids of tags based on old name values(in current jsonb tags Column)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this query worked for me :

```
UPDATE article artc
       SET tags= array_to_json(ARRAY(
select id from tag where tag.name in (select tag #>> '{}' from article , jsonb_array_elements(tags) tag  where id =artc.id)));
```